# Accidentally uninstalled xorg hwe package and lost graphic interface

Tags: xorg

I was trying to get a better performance with my touchpad, installing synaptics packages.

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

It complained about unmet dependencies, pointing to `xserver-xorg-core` package.

Then I noticed I had different xorg packages installed and tried to switch the mentioned one, by running:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

But then, it started uninstalling xorg hwe stuff, it uninstalled like 9 packages or so.

I then proceeded to install the synaptics packages I needed and rebooted.

No graphics then. Tried to reinstall hwe:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04` (done a cache search to remember it)

was successful, but installed only 2 packages and nothing changed

tl:dr

Do I need to reinstall xorg core hwe packs so I can restore GUI or what?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying several methods, I ended up just reinstalling ubuntu, so no longer can receive support on this, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for at least following up with your own solution, even if it was a re-install. The question will probably be closed as non-reproducible.